# How to construct whole rdd into one element?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have rdd like this

```
A,1335952933,1
A,1335953754,0
A,1335994294,1
A,1335995228,0
B,1336001513,1
B,1336002622,0
B,1336006905,1
B,1336007462,0


rdd.first
A,1335952933,1
```

when I get rdd.first it shows A,1335952933,1 but I want to get whole rdd as a one element seperated by commas like this

```
rdd.first
 A,1335952933,1,A,1335953754,0,A,1335994294,1,A,1335995228,0,B,1336001513,1,B,1336002622,0,
B,1336007462,0
```

I can do it using collect and mkString scala but I heard collect is not a good solution in large data sets Is there any other way to do this using rdd operations ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but I want to get whole rdd as a one element

`collect` is not recommended exactly for this reason. collect transfers the entire data of the RDD collection to the driver application (which runs on a single machine) which is not possible for large dataset since you would get out of memory exception. so if you really want this you take the route of `collect` and `mkString` and avoid using it on large RDDs.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer I got the point that you explained

Answer (score 0):

`collect` is not recommended because it causes whole dataset to be trasferred to the driver. But your case requies transferring it anyway, so there is nothing wrong with `collect` & `mkString` here.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer I got the point that you explained